# Git conflicts after squash merge

Tags: git, git-merge, git-squash

I have a master branch and a dev branch.
e.g.

```
master: A--B--C

dev: A--B--C--D--E
```

then I want to release D and E, so I create a release-1.0 branch from master, squash merge dev to release-1.0, so

```
release-1.0: A--B--C--F(D&E)
```

after I release, I merge release-1.0 to master.

```
master: A--B--C--F(D&E)
```

then I continue my new changes on dev

```
dev: A--B--C--D--E--G--H
```

and conflicts happens when I create release-2.0 from master and merge dev to it.

That's the problem I encountered. I realize this is not the right way to use merge squash, I do some search and didn't find a good solution.

Comment: Is there a way to tell git DE squash to F, so just treat them as same when next merge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend only using regular merges between `dev` and `master`. If you really want to squash, you can create a `feature` branch for it, then squash it into dev once it's done.

Regarding the situation at hand, you can rebase `dev` commits `G` and `H` onto `master` like this:

```
git checkout dev
git rebase --onto master <E commit hash>
```

This is what you'll end up with:

```
* dbd43d8 (HEAD -> dev) H
* c203a3d G
* 39a258a (master) F(D&E)
* 538454c C
* 8aa2e42 B
* 2f3facb A
```

Then you can simply fast-forwar merge the `master` branch.

Comment: Yeah, I understand this is the right way to use merge squash. what if I do really need to do a squash merge from dev to master, I'm thinking is there a better way to handle it instead of resolving the conflict.